# Regex to ensure a specific word does not occur in the middle of a pattern

Tags: regex

I have a regex which matches a range of characters in a list, but I'd like to prevent it from matching a word.

My Regex is:

```
^widget/([\w\d~]+)/?(?:[\w\d~]+)/?$
```

I'd like it to match like this:

- `widget/JQYHHU` - View widget, should match
- `widget/JQYHHU/` - View widget, should match
- `widget/JQYHHU/bag-of-screws` - View widget, should match
- `widget/JQYHHU/bag-of-screws/` - View widget, should match
- `widget/add` - View widget, should **not** match
- `widget/add/` - View widget, should **not** match

Is it possible to add in a condition so it will match characters, but not if they spell the word 'add'?

Comment: Other than add, are there any other words you don't wish to match?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
^widget/(?!add)([\w\d~]+)/?(?:[\w\d~]+)/?$
```

This is a *zero-width negative lookahead assertion*; basically it says "Standing where I am right now, ensure that if I look forward I do **not** see the pattern `add`, but do not move the cursor position when I'm done."

Read up on it here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: you need to add the dash to the character class, and then the regex can be simplified too this way: `^widget/(?!add)(?:([\w\d~-]+)/?)+$`

Comment: Thanks for the reference. The terminology is sometimes difficult to remember.