# awk match lines that has a "(" but no ")"

Tags: awk

I am writing a parser in awk to a certain file format which relies heavily on parenthesis.
For my script to know which section it is it needs to be able to interpret them in the correct manner

One part of the file could look like this

```
        : (MyIntranet
                    :add_routed_domain ()
```

If a line contains a "(" but no ending ")" that means we have begun a new section.
If a line contains both a beginning "(" and an ending ")" this means this line does not start a new section, it is only a container for a data value contained within the "()"

So in order for my awk parser to understand the difference I am trying to construct a regexp doing this:

A new section begins if we have a line with one "(" anywhere on the line, but the last character on the line is not ")"
An section ends if we have a line ending with ")" but there was no "(" on the line.

I read here: [Regex to ensure a specific word does not occur in the middle of a pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10363957/regex-to-ensure-a-specific-word-does-not-occur-in-the-middle-of-a-pattern)
That you can use (?!WORD) to not match WORD

I constructed a regexp which looks like this:

```
\(.+(?!\))
```

My belief is that this would match a "(" and any characters after, but not if the last character is a ")"

I have put the two lines in a file called match3.input

```
user@lab-client:~$ awk '/\(.+(?!\))/ { print $0 }' match3.input
user@lab-client:~$
```

So obviously I am doing something wrong as I would expect the above command to return the line:

```
: (MyIntranet
```

If I remove the (?!)) the expression returns both lines as expected

```
user@lab-client:~/bork$ awk '/\(.+/ { print $0 }' match3.input
    : (MyIntranet
                    :add_routed_domain ()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expressions in `awk` are [POSIX EREs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04), which do not have the `(?...)` extensions.

In this case an inverted [character class](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05) can be used to write an equivalent expression:

```
awk '/\([^(]*$/' match3.input
```

Comment: I am trying to apply this to two other examples:

Comment: I am trying to apply this to two other examples: Matching lines that has a "(" anywhere in them but no ")" as last character . /[^(]*\)$/ But I think I am missing something.

Comment: I mean match a line ending with a ")" but the line should have no "(" anywhere before it.

Comment: I think I finally got it with: /:.+ \([^)]*$/

Comment: For that specific example you would need to anchor the expression at both the beginning and the end `/^[^(]*)$/`.  Slightly more complex processing can be done by counting parenthesis, but for parenthesis in strings, comments, etc. you may want to look at [tag:lex] and [tag:yacc].

Comment: But I cannot seem to get a regexp matching any line ending with a ")", but only if the line contains no "(" before it

Comment: There was a mistake in the previous comment, the following ERE has the described behavior. `^[^(]*\)$`